# Using arithmetic progression sum to show an algorithm is both $\Theta(n^2)$ and $O(n^2)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Exercise 4 in http://discrete.gr/complexity/ askes to give an arithmetic progression sum to show that the following algorithm is both $O(n^2)$ and $\Theta(n^2)$.

```
b = []
n.times do
  m = a[ 0 ]
  mi = 0
  a.each_with_index do |element, i|
    if element < m
      m = element
      mi = i
    end
  end
  a.delete_at( mi )
  b << m
end
```

sudo code:

```
sorted_array = []
for i in unsorted_array
  for j in unsorted_array
    if unsorted_array[j] < unsorted_array[i]
      m = unsorted_array[j]
  unsorted_array.remove(m)
  sorted_array.add(m)
```

I think I understand that you want to show that the progressive sum of $n, n - 1, .., n - (n - 1)$ is $\Theta(n^2)$.  And I see that the worse case scenario limit approaches $n^2$, but I do not understand how to write a proof of this.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you explain the program in some pseudo-code or some simpler format. Some of the statements (like `each_with_index` and `b << m` are unclear .

Comment: The link says it is selection sort. The Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) has the analysis of the algorithm.

Comment: If something is $\Theta(n^2)$ then it's also $O(n^2)$ by definition.  And I agree with tpb261's first comment.

Comment: @AntonioVargas to be clear I know that the algorithm is $O(n^2)$ but want to prove that it is also $\Theta(n^2)$. $\Theta(n^2)$ is not guaranteed by $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n+(n-1)+(n-2)+\cdots+1=\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}2\in\Theta(n^2)\subset O(n^2)$$

Comment: This looks to be the correct answer but could you provide a little more information.  I see where n+(n-1)+..+1 comes from but don't see how that simplifies to $n(n+1)/2$ or how that implies to $\Theta(n^2)$. Thanks.

Comment: For the first question in your comment, see http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalNumbers.htm

Comment: For the second question in your comment, how do you define the class $\Theta(n^2)$?

Comment: Oh duh, because n(n+1)/2 => n^2+n/2 => n^2/2 + n + 1/2 the theta notation of the equation is n^2. thanks.  I'll look through the link you provided to better understand the summation.